# MongoDB: Creating index very slow

Tags: index, mongodb

I'm currently creating an index on a mongo database and so far it has taken about 52 hours. I've worked with large(r) Mongo databases before but creating an index has never taken this long. My collection has 1 billion rows, and I'm creating the index on a single string field which always has a length of 12.

Should I just leave it running, or is it potentially broken and should just be stopped?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the MongoDB Version(x,y,z)?

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan 4.2.1

Comment: What is the RAM size? What is mongodb installation type? Single Replica set or sharded cluster?

Comment: @Mani 24GB. It's a single instance server running on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Index creation will be show in the mongo error logs. You can monitor the progress of the index creation. 52 hours is very slow. Can you post the masked error log here?